# Increment a variable timely in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, date, variable

I want to increment a variable by one every 3 seconds. Is there any way to do that using bash?

I had a program running in infinite loop in which I am doing some stuff with a variable; I want to increment that variable, say, every 3 seconds, I am not supposed to use sleep.

Comment: Do you need to do this asynchronously, i.e. while other things happens, without, say, sleeping for three seconds?

Comment: Yeah, I can't use sleep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bash`, the `$SECONDS` special variable is already incremented once every second like in `ksh` where the feature comes from.

It's initialised to 0 at the time the shell starts (or from the value of the `$SECONDS` environment variable if it's there), but you can also set its value by hand.

However note that `bash`'s implementation (contrary to that of ksh93, mksh or zsh, the latter two used to have the same bug but it was fixed after I reported it) is [broken](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg17783.html) in that it is incremented when the system clock passes an exact second mark.

So, if you set it to `0` at 12:00:00.1 or 12:00:00.9 it will change to `1` at 12:00:01 (so 9/10 second later in the first case and 1/10 second later in the second)

You may want to switch to zsh, mksh or ksh93 instead.

And then you just need to use `$((SECONDS*3))` for something that is incremented by 3 every second or `$((SECONDS/3))` for something that is incremented by 1 every 3 seconds.

In `ksh93`, you could define the `get` discipline of an arbitrary variable as `$((SECONDS*3))`:

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
var.get() {
  .sh.value=$((int(SECONDS*3)))
}
SECONDS=0

# testing:
echo "$var"; sleep 1; echo "$var"
```

gives:

```
0
3
```

Still in ksh93, you could define a `type` of variable that gets incremented by any arbitrary number every seconds with something like:

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
SECONDS=0
typeset -T auto_incremented=(
  typeset -F start
  typeset -i initial=0
  typeset -i increment=1
  function get {
    .sh.value=$((_.initial + int((SECONDS - _.start) * _.increment)))
  }
  function create {
    ((_.start = SECONDS))
  }
  function set {
    _.initial=${.sh.value}
    ((_.start = SECONDS))
  }
)

# testing:
auto_incremented var
var.increment=2

echo "$var"; sleep 2; echo "$var"

var=10; echo "$var"; sleep 2; echo "$var"
```

Which here gives:

```
0
4
10
14
```

Though `bash` copied quite a few features from ksh, it didn't copy *disciplines*, *types* or a floating point `$SECONDS`.

In `bash`, one approach you could take is run some background process that sends a signal every second to `bash` and install a *trap* on that signal that updates the variable, like:

```
#! /bin/bash -
var=0 SECONDS=0; trap '((var = SECONDS * 3))' ALRM

ksh93 -c '
  t=0 SECONDS=0
  while
    sleep "$((++t - SECONDS))" && kill -s ALRM -- "$1" 2> /dev/null
  do
    : nothing
  done' ksh "$$" &

# testing:
echo "$var"; sleep 2; echo "$var"
```

Note that we can't just increment `$var` in the trap handler as traps are only processed in-between non-builtin commands and if one of those commands take more than 1 second, during which more than one SIGALRM signal is sent, only one will be processed.

Here we're using a `ksh93` inline script to do the signal sending every second, but you could use `zsh`, `perl`, `python`... instead if available.

Answer (score 1):

A horrible solution:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
somevar=0
somefile=$(mktemp)
echo "$somevar" > "$somefile"
while true; do sleep 3; ((somevar++)); echo "$somevar" > "$somefile" ;done &

  while true; do

    sleep 1
    avar="$(cat "$somefile")"
    echo "my var has value $avar"

  done
```

Certainly NOT precise with the times and NOWHERE near realtime-ready...

Answer (score -1):

Below is code

```
 i=10
    for ((j=1;j<=count_of_sequence;j++)); do echo $i; sleep 10;i=$(($i+1)); done
```

output

```
10
11
12
13
14
```

Comment: This is unfortunately exactly what the user does not want to do. They want their variable to be updated every three seconds _while doing other things_ (not while sleeping).